# Cannot get the value href attribute even when it is diplayed when the whole dictionary is printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape links from a website with the help of following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_links(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    link = soup.find('a', class_="eds-media-card-content__action-link")
    print("Link attributes:", link.attrs)
    for k, v in link.attrs.items():
            print(k, v)

    print("Link: ", link.attrs['href'])

get_links("https://www.eventbrite.com/d/online/all-events/?page=1")
```

The output of the following code is:

```
Link attributes: {'tabindex': '-1', 'href': 'https://www.eventbrite.com/e/livestream-jon-kabat-zinn-cultivating-mindfulness-at-this-critical-time-tickets-101254729622?aff=ebdssbonlinesearch', 'class': ['eds-media-card-content__action-link'], 'aria-label': 'See more of Livestream Jon Kabat-Zinn: Cultivating Mindfulness at this Critical Time'}
tabindex -1
href 
class ['eds-media-card-content__action-link']
aria-label See more of Livestream Jon Kabat-Zinn: Cultivating Mindfulness at this Critical Time
Link:
```

As it can be seen, href attribute is not empty in the above dictionary, but when I try to access it, an empty string is returned.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The problem has been solved (partially). I was running it on jupyter notebook on my pc, and the link wasn't displayed. But when I put it in a .py file and run it, the link is displayed. 
Still don't know the reason of jupyter notebook behaving like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.To get the href value just use

`link['href']` 
or 
`link.get('href')` 
or 
`link.attrs.get('href')`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_links(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    link = soup.find('a', class_="eds-media-card-content__action-link")
    print("Link: ", link['href'])

get_links("https://www.eventbrite.com/d/online/all-events/?page=1")
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: doesn't work. My output is `Link: `. Can you see the link on your pc?

Comment: @RoommanIsraili : see attached snapshot.Hope you have some other problem?

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing that out. I was running the code on jupyter notebook and it was not working (don't know the reason). But when I put it in a normal .py file and run it, the link is displayed. My original code works too.

Comment: @RoommanIsraili the coolest way to thank someone for his answer is just by accepting his answer by ticking the check mark beside the answer, you can up-vote as well.